# Bind HTML5 dropdown using Jquery from websql database

Tags: jquery, binding, html-select

I want to set dropdown selected value from jquery.

I tried different approaches mentioned below but none of them is working.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
<select id="interviewertyp" name="interviewerType" data-theme="b" data-mini="true"
data-native-menu="false" onchange="interviewerTypeFn(this.value)">
<option value="0">Insured</option>
<option value="1">Tenant</option>
<option value="2">Other</option>
</select><br />
</div>
```

JQUERY APPROACH:

```
var valu = "";
if (row['rdWhowasinter'] == "Y")
valu = 0;
else if (row['rdWhowasinter'] == "N")
valu = 1;
else if (row['rdWhowasinter'] == "O")
valu = 2;
else {

}
alert(valu);

valu = "Insured";
$("#interviewertyp").selectmenu('refresh');
$("#interviewertyp option").each(function () {
if ($(this).text() == valu) {
alert($(this).text());

$(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
}
});
$("#interviewertyp").selectmenu('refresh');
$("#interviewertyp").selectmenu('refresh');
$("#interviewertyp option:selected").val(valu);
alert($("#interviewertyp option:selected").val())
$("#interviewertyp option:selected").val(valu);
$("#interviewertyp").selectmenu('refresh');
$("#interviewertyp").val("1");
```

Jquery Version : 1.7.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a second dropdown menu if a certain value in the first dropdown is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562141/how-to-display-a-second-dropdown-menu-if-a-certain-value-in-the-first-dropdown-i)

Comment: after setting the value from the db I checked in alert $("#interviewertypoption:selected").val(valu);it shows the new value from the db but the UI does not get updated.